# How to use adsense after some time of page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, adsense

I've created a little social networking website which is working fine, 
but in wall page google ads is not showing,
its showing and working fine in other pages 
but in wall page not showing because the page content is showing with js

So i think there's a problem of keywords and description issue

i just want to know how to use google ads after sometime

i try

```
function show(){
//My Adsense Code But Still Not Working
}

setTimeout('show()',5000);
```

Comment: How can you know if it works , if the ads doesn't appear anyway on that page?
Why not resolving the main issue - why the ads doesn't appear on the certain page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're making serious money with adsense, Google will give you access to premium ads including a very customizable api. If you got there you can format the ads in very different ways and supply the keywords you would like to be used.